# How to Find the characters between two strings of characters in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with a lengthy text string in it stored as HUGEBLOB) which im trying to extract key information from. I can convert the HUGEBLOB to usable text using

```
UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.substr(searchableattrib,1000,1))
```

This has a text string in it of:

{"newValue":"#01D","fieldName":"U_MP_REASON_CODE","oldValue":"#00","scenarioName":"LIVE","pageName":"SKU WORKSPACE","intersectionKey":"LOC: FR01, ITEM: 16651903"}

Im aiming to get out of this, the 16651903 and trying to do this by using a regexp_substr but struggling. i found some code which allows me to find the word ITEM: followed by a space, but it was set to only return alpha characters, but i need to return all characters before the next speech marks"

Current code is:

```
select auditid, regexp_substr( UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.substr(searchableattrib,1000,1)),'ITEM:[[:space:]]*([[:alpha:]_]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as item, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.substr(searchableattrib,1000,1)) from auditlog
where auditid = '3622fe86-0db7-4c79-afb1-b7cdcc99c0e4'
```

which gives me an audit ID referance (just a string of alphanumeric characters, and then a blank column for ITEM as there is no alpha characters following the word ITEM:

Ive tried searching but as im using a string, im struggling to find a similar question and understand it.

I can deal with the utl_raw and cast etc separately if anyone can help with a select statement using a column containing the text above, that will pull out only the ITEM code of 16651903

the 16651903 could be various lengths and could start with an alpha character, so i need only the text following ITEM: but before the speech mark

Thanks

EDIT: have got further (I think) by moving away from regular expression and using substr and instr as per:

```
select SUBSTR(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.substr(searchableattrib,1000,1)), INSTR((UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.substr(searchableattrib,1000,1))),'ITEM: ') + LENGTH('ITEM: '),  LENGTH(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.substr(searchableattrib,1000,1)))-1-INSTR((UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.substr(searchableattrib,1000,1))),'ITEM: ')-LENGTH('ITEM: ') 
 )  as item from auditlog
```

its messy, but giving me mostly the right detail, some input data is of a differant form, so working on that next

e,g,

{"newValue":"#01D","fieldName":"U_MP_REASON_CODE","oldValue":"#00","scenarioName":"LIVE","pageName":"SKU MASTER","intersectionKey":"ITEM: 13216683, LOC: DE01"}

as the ITEM and LOC are in differant orders.

Comment: Using a regular expression like: `(?<=ITEM: )([0-9]*)`, you can do it easy (see: https://regex101.com/r/ZjWJpz/1 ).  Another option, maybe better, because your data seems to be in JSON format, use a function to read this JSON data, and no substring tricks... (see: [Using PL/SQL Object Types for JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/using-PLSQL-object-types-for-JSON.html#GUID-F0561593-D0B9-44EA-9C8C-ACB6AA9474EE))

Comment: @Luuk Oracle does not support look-around in regular expressions so that regular expression will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like below. Inner SUBSTR() will find 'ITEM:' text, take everything after that and outer SUBSTR() will take text before double-quote or comma character. TRIM() will remove spaces (if there are any) before or after item part of interest. double-quotes and commas are replaced with some character that is not contained within string (in this code it is |) which is then used as the end of the item code:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (ID, STR_1) AS
        ( Select 1, '{"newValue":"#01D","fieldName":"U_MP_REASON_CODE","oldValue":"#00","scenarioName":"LIVE","pageName":"SKU WORKSPACE","intersectionKey":"LOC: FR01, ITEM: 16651903"}' From Dual Union All
          Select 2, '{"newValue":"#01D","fieldName":"U_MP_REASON_CODE","oldValue":"#00","scenarioName":"LIVE","pageName":"SKU MASTER","intersectionKey":"ITEM: 13216683, LOC: DE01"}' From Dual
        )
```

Don't know how your BLOB is formed, I used search for 'ITEM:' (without the space after) for possibility that there is no space after or there are two spaces. That is why the TRIM() is there...

```sql
--    M a i n    S Q L 
Select  ID, SubStr( Replace(Replace(TRIM(SubStr(STR_1, InStr(STR_1, 'ITEM:', 1, 1) + LENGTH('ITEM:'))), '"', '|'), ',', '|'), 1, 
                    InStr(Replace(Replace(TRIM(SubStr(STR_1, InStr(STR_1, 'ITEM:', 1, 1) + LENGTH('ITEM:'))), '"', '|'), ',', '|'), '|', 1, 1) - 1 ) "STR_ITEM"
From    tbl
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
        ID STR_ITEM     
---------- -------------
         1 16651903     
         2 13216683   */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON parser to parse JSON and then extract the relevant sub-string from the extracted JSON value:

```sql
SELECT auditid,
       SUBSTR(intersectionKey, INSTR(intersectionKey, 'ITEM: ') + 6) AS item
FROM   auditlog
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         searchableattrib,
         '$'
         COLUMNS (
           intersectionKey VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.intersectionKey'
         )
       )
WHERE auditid = '3622fe86-0db7-4c79-afb1-b7cdcc99c0e4';
```

or:

```sql
SELECT auditid,
       SUBSTR(intersectionKey, INSTR(intersectionKey, 'ITEM: ') + 6) AS item
FROM   (
  SELECT auditid,
         JSON_VALUE(searchableattrib, '$.intersectionKey') AS intersectionKey
  FROM   auditlog
  WHERE auditid = '3622fe86-0db7-4c79-afb1-b7cdcc99c0e4'
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE auditlog (
  auditid          VARCHAR2(36),
  searchableattrib BLOB CHECK (searchableattrib IS JSON)
);

INSERT INTO auditlog (
  auditid,
  searchableattrib
) VALUES (
  '3622fe86-0db7-4c79-afb1-b7cdcc99c0e4',
  '{"newValue":"#01D","fieldName":"U_MP_REASON_CODE","oldValue":"#00","scenarioName":"LIVE","pageName":"SKU WORKSPACE","intersectionKey":"LOC: FR01, ITEM: 16651903"}'
);
```

Both output:

| AUDITID | ITEM |
| --- | --- |
| 3622fe86-0db7-4c79-afb1-b7cdcc99c0e4 | 16651903 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UPz6mfSt)